# get_relationships not fetching data using sugarcrm api

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using the SugarCRM API get_relationships() to fetch Cases related to an Account. I'm getting Account data properly and passing the session & Account id to get the related data. But get_relationships() is giving me only field name and not field values. Below is my code:

```
$get_relationships_parameters = array(
    'session' => $session_id,
    'module_name' => 'Accounts',
    'module_id' => $accountId,
    'link_field_name' => 'cases',
    //'related_fields' => array('cases.id','cases.name'),
    'related_module_query' => "",
    'deleted' => 0
);
$casedata = call("get_relationships", $get_relationships_parameters, $url);
```

I am getting the result as:

```
stdClass Object
(
 [entry_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 
                [module_name] => Cases
                [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [deleted] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [name] => deleted
                                [value] => 0
                            )


        )

            )

    )

  [relationship_list] => Array
    (
    )
```

As you can see the values are empty for id & [name] => stdClass Object is missing. If i comment out the line 'related_fields' => array('cases.id','cases.name'), I am getting a blank array as:

```
stdClass Object
( 
 [entry_list] => Array
    (
    )

[relationship_list] => Array
    (
    )
 )
```

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter related_fields can not be empty and that is why there is a blank array in your response.

About the content in the related_fields, the fields should be without the table name:

```
'related_fields' => array('id','name'),
```